# Apply first row of text to set docvars

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to add a docvars using the first row of text in the file.

```
docvars(myCorpus, "Dept.") <- stri_sub(gnbtxts, 1, 8)
```

returns the first 8 characters of the file, but I am not able to source how to return the entire contents of the first row to be applied as the docvars.

Comment: Without some information about your object `gnbtxts`, as well as what "the first row" means or what it looks like, it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: gnbtxts is a collection of texts (.txt) from a directory to be used to create the corpus.  Firs first row is the first line of text from each file to containing the department name the .txt file has been provided by.

Comment: From the environment ..$ texts : chr [1:19] " Health \nEliminating barriers to reproductive health01 February 2018FREDERICTON (GNB) - The number of publicly"| __truncated__ " Justice and Public Safety \nVolunteers sought for court support program in Saint John region01 February.  In this case, am trying to apply " Health" as docvars or "Justice and Public Safety" for next docvars to be assigned.

Comment: So you want the docvar value to the be the term from the first line of each element of the character vector `gnbtxts`? That's not a **quanteda** question, but if you rephrase the question with the information about the contexts of the character vector, and an example, then this question has a much better chance of being answered.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Not sure how to rephrase the question, isn't docvars unique to quanteda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **str_extract** provides a workable solution by extracting of all text up-to the first occurrence of new row along with a trim to handle any leading spaces.

docvars(myCorpus, "Dept.") <- str_trim(str_extract(gnbtxts, "[^\n]+"))